# HTTP Header Remove/Change ETag after setup Cache-Control:no-cache

Tags: iis, http-headers

How to remove cached files in browser by server response?

I have accidentally setup

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
```

Then Lots of my client's browser cached javascript files. I have change the server http status and new response should have

```
Expire:0
Cache-Control:no-store
```

But the cached file does not get latest files. So I was reading some article and tried to remove/change ETag header and tried adding

```
<customHeaders>
        <add name="ETag" value=" " />
</customHeaders>
```

But it does not work. I also tried to disable all cache from Output Caching in IIS.

[image]

But it does not work.

How can I make the browser gets latest files without doing by user side?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Disable client cache in iis you could use the HTTP Response Headers feature:

1)Open iis manager, select your site.

2)Doble click HTTP Response Headers from the middle pane.

[image]

3)On the HTTP Response Headers page, in the Actions pane, click Set Common Headers.

4)In the Set Common HTTP Response Headers dialog box, select the Expire Web content check box and select one of the following options:

- Select Immediately if you want the content to expire immediately after it is sent in a response.
- Select After if you want the content to expire periodically. Then, in the corresponding boxes, type an integer and select a time interval at which content expires. For example, type 1 and select Days if you want the content to expire daily.
- Select On (in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)) if you want the content to expire on a specific day and at a specific time. Then, in the corresponding boxes, select a date and time at which the content expires.

[image]

If you have access to the source code mall modern browsers will treat resources such as a CSS, Javascript as new versions if you append a query string to them which is unique.

E.g

http://www.example.com/test.js?v=1.1

You can disable cache for specific file and folder by using the location tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- Specific file -->
  <location path="test.js">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>

  <!-- Folder including subfolders -->
  <location path="folder/subfolder">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```